# Passing an array as a value to Zend_Filter

Tags: zend-framework

I'm trying to implode an array by using the Zend_Filter_Interface.

Here's my simplified test case.

```
class My_Filter_Implode implements Zend_Filter_Interface
{
    public function filter($value)
    {
        return implode(',', $value);
    }
}
```

The input will be an array.

```
$rawInput = array('items' => array('a', 'b', 'c'));

$validators = array(
    'items' => array()
)

$filters = array(
    'items' => 'Implode'
);

$filterInput = new Zend_Filter_Input($filters, $validators, $rawInput, $options);
```

I would like the filter to transform array('a', 'b', 'c') to a string 'a,b,c'. It is instead applying the filter to each item in the array. How can the value passed to filter() be passed as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter seems to be OK. The problem is in `Zend_Filter_Input`, which passes individually the values in the array to the filters and validators.

There is a discussion thread about this problem, along with some possible workarounds here: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Filter-Input-and-Arrays-td653511.html

Hope that helps,

Comment: It helped, thank you. It's too bad the ZF patch for the traverseArray decorator never made it in. http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4354