# Zend Validators and multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, zend-validate, zend-framework

How do i validate multidimensional array in Zend Framework (Zend_Filter_Input)?

Example:

- Input must be array
- Input must have 'roles' and 'name'
- 'roles' must be array
- All element in 'roles' must be array
- All element in 'roles' must have 'name' and 'id', 'access' is optional
- 'id' must be int
- 'access' must be array

---

```
$input = array(
    'roles' => array(
        array('name' => 'Test', 'id' => 1),
        array('name' => 'Test2', 'id' => 2, 'access' => array('read', 'write'))
    ),
    'name' => 'blabla'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question some days ago: [Passing an array as a value to Zend_Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252293/passing-an-array-as-a-value-to-zend-filter)

In short, if you use `Zend_Filter_Input`, it will pass the array values individually to the associated validators. So, it's not possible to use the array as a whole, but the individual components.

**EDIT**: A possible solution would be to create your own specific `Zend_Validate` class and include all the checks in the `isValid` method, something like the following:

```
class MyValidator extends Zend_Validate_Abstract
{
    const MESSAGE = 'message';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::MESSAGE => "Invalid format for the array"
    );

    public function isValid($value)
    {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $this->_error();
            return false;
        }

        // ...

        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Does this mean Morfi would have to apply all of the items in his 'logical validation' list manually from his client code? And if so, where would be the appropriate place to do this? In the form model?

Comment: @cantera25: I've updated my answer with the approach I would take.